# How do i have the program print a different response each time?

Tags: python

I need to extend my original program to print a different response for every person. I'm not sure what to do to have it print a different response each time. I tried an array but i couldn't get that too work.

```
print("Hi, ",input("What is your name?"),#response here#
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Check out the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

Comment: Use a dictionary?

Comment: Put the input name in a variable, use that to look up the response in a dictionary, then print the greeing message that combines both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `random.choice()` function provided by the random module:

```py
import random

greetings = ["How are you!", "Why are you?", "What are you?"]
print("Hi, ", input("What is your name?"), random.choice(greetings))
```

This will give you random choices from the `greetings` list everytime.